# Changing the order of entries in the PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a feeling this question has been asked before but here it is in the simplest form:

```
Plot[
 {0.3 x^2, 0.5 x^2, 0.7 x^2}, {x, -3, 3},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
 ]
```

[image]

I tried the `AbsoluteOptions@ Plot[{0.3 x^2, 0.5 x^2, 0.7 x^2}, {x, -3, 3},  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]` but could not find something to work with.

**Question** What I want to do is to write out the legend in reverse order so that colors match up. Is there a built-in option to rearrange `PlotLegends` entries.

Thanks.

Comment: Or reverse the order of the functions, i.e., `Plot[Evaluate[Reverse@{0.3 x^2, 0.5 x^2, 0.7 x^2}], {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LineLegend` with the option `LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"`:

```
Plot[{0.3 x^2, 0.5 x^2, 0.7 x^2}, {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions", LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"]]
```

[image]

**Note:** `LegendLayout -> Grid @* Reverse` gives the same result.

Comment: Thanks. `PlotLegends` do appear in the `Options[Plot]` but not in `AbsoluteOptions` that I tried. What is the main difference between the two? Is there a hierarchy diagram I can study that can clarify the relationships between `Plot` and its various options?

Comment: @Syed, the short tutorial [Manipulating Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingOptions.html) may be useful.