# How to organize these plot legends?

Tags: plotting, legending

I have some plots which are obtained from a long numerical integration. I have named each plot and then have tried to show them in a single plot using `Show` command. Here, for the sake of simplicity I have used some simple functions as my plots as follows

```
p1 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}];
p2 = Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dotted}];
p3 = Plot[x^4, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Black}];
```

when I use `show`

```
Show[Legended[p1, 
  LineLegend[{Directive[Thickness[0.006], Dashed, Black]}, {"p1"}]], 
 Legended[p2, 
  LineLegend[{Directive[Thickness[0.006], Dotted, Black]}, {"p2"}]], 
 Legended[p3, 
  LineLegend[{Directive[Thickness[0.006], Black]}, {"p3"}]]]
```

the following image is produced
[image]

which has ugly legends.

1: Why the length of legend line is different for solid one? and how can I equalize their lengths?

2: How can I change the vertical space of the legends? in this case I want to reduce them.

3: How can I change the position of all legends (as a whole) with respect to the plot? for example  top or bottom of the plot?

Comment: I don't know why, but I know the workaround: use a single LineLegend: `Legended[Show[{p1,p2,p3}], LineLegend[{...}, {...}]]`. If you can, use a single `Plot` to plot all three things. This is slightly more convenient and allows you not to have to write the styles twice (one for Plot, one for the legend).

Comment: For 2, see LegendMarkerSize in LineLegend docs; for 3 see Legended / Placed in Legended docs. These work if you have a single legend, not three, as I suggested above. I'll leave a full answer with examples to others.

Comment: Changing the order of the legends was recently [answered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256344/changing-the-order-of-entries-in-the-plotlegends)

Comment: @SzabolcsThanks by the way as I said I can't use a single plot.

Comment: @Syed Thanks but this is not my question!

Comment: Please add 'legending' tag to your question. It is specifically about legends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
show = Show[
    Legended[p1, LineLegend[{Directive[Thickness[0.006], Dashed, Black]}, {"p1"}]], 
    Legended[p2, LineLegend[{Directive[Thickness[0.006], Dotted, Black]}, {"p2"}]], 
    Legended[p3, LineLegend[{Directive[Thickness[0.006], Black]}, {"p3"}]]];
```

Process `show` to get the main plot and legends and construct a new legend with the option `"Spacings"` using the extracted information:

```
combinedplot = show[[1, 1, 1]];

combinedlegend = LineLegend[## & @@ 
    Transpose[Cases[show, LineLegend[a_, b_] :> Flatten@{a, b}, All]], 
   "Spacings" -> {1, 1}];

Legended[combinedplot, combinedlegend]
```

[image]

```
Legended[combinedplot,
    Placed[Append[LegendLayout -> {"Row",1}] @ combinedlegend, Top]]
```

[image]

Replace `"Spacings" -> {1, 1}` with `"Spacings" -> {1, 0}` to get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, they are what I wanted

Comment: one more question: if I want to hold the legends in the right of plot, but raise a little, how do that?

Comment: @Wisdom, try `Legended[combinedplot,Placed[ combinedlegend, {After, .6}]]`. Play with different values in place of  `.6` to move the legend up/down.

Comment: You're right, Thanks